# Store JSON locally versus on server

Tags: json, storage

I am currently developing a web application that has to deal with a lot of json data to draw various things on a map e.g Polygons and Points. I also have json data drawing charts. At the moment I have the data locally but wondering is this the best way when dealing with a lot of data?

Is it better to store it in a database on a server and request it? Or if its better to store it locally, should I be using things like local storage or something else?

I don't have any need to update any of the json, simple retrieve it.

I want to do it in a performant way so not sure which is better

Would really appreciate some advice

Comment: Unfortunately this is likely to get closed off as being too broad, as SO is for code-specific questions that can be answered, not merely discussed. However, to try to answer your question, it depends on multiple factors. In short, if the JSON relates entirely to the individual user, and you have no need to receive and interrogate the data centrally, there's no reason not to store it locally, using either `localStorage` (via `JSON.stringify()`) or WebSQL.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, didnt realise its not something I should be asking here. I appreciate you answering

Comment: It's difficult; I often have broad questions which I know will get me flamed if I ask them on SO, yet you're thinking... OK, but it's still a valid question. Where do I ask? Hopefully you can resolve the issue. `localStorage` is easier to use than WebSQL but WebSQL allows for much greater searching and arrangement of the data in the runtime environment - it's essentially an in-browser simulation of a database, whereas `localStorage` works like JavaScript objects.

Comment: Great, thanks so much again

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is - there is no *best* way, as it depends on the purpose of your application and the data youre considering.

---

This depends entirely on the purpose of your application, and your examination of the cost/benefit of having data persisted on a server.

Ask yourself questions like the following:

How long do you need this data to persist?

How expensive is it for you if you lose the data?

What other options do you have at your disposal? Have you considered NoSQL solutions or cloud-based memory storage of any sort?

How much data do you plan to store?

How often will you be retrieving the data?

In exactly what format do you want to store and retrieve the data?

What options are you looking at in terms of a server for storing persisted data?

You mentioned local storage - is the data *only* relevant to a current user/session, or is the data relevant to yourself or other users? If the latter, then local storage may not be adequate. It is, of course, much cheaper than other options to persist the data.

If you are going to go with long term persistence, then check out [PostgreSQL's latest features for JSON data types](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/New_in_postgres_10#Full_Text_Search_support_for_JSON_and_JSONB).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The data won't change at all. Not expensive if I lose the data since the data will be a copy. I plan to store about 50mb . I data with essentially every interaction on the web app. It will be stored in JSON format. It sounds like local storage/websql is my best option. My biggest fear is the performance of the web app if I am storing a lot of data but it sounds like I might be ok?